# With a Bootstrap Modal, how can I stop it moving position in the DOM during show/hide?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

With a [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), when the modal is displayed, it appears in the DOM where I've actually placed it in the code.

When the modal is hidden, it's moved out of the DOM and instead placed down as the last element prior to the closing `</body>` tag.

Is there built-in bootstrap to ensure the modal code says where I deliberately placed it in the DOM, even when hidden? I need it where I've placed it because it contains form fields that makes up part of larger `<form>` outside of the modal container.

**Current Workaround**
Currently, when the modal is hidden (either on the initial page load or when the user takes action to close the modal), I move to back to where I want it.

```
// put modal back to where I need it in the DOM when I user closes the modal
$('#my_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  m = $('#my_modal').detach();
  $('#my_form').append(m);
});

// put modal back to where I need it when the page is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  m = $('#my_modal').detach();
  $('#my_form').append(m);
});
```

Comment: strange bootstrap usaly doesn't move the content of the modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @madalin-ivascu's comment, it turns out by default bootstrap doesn't move modal code. After that comment, I searched my whole codebase for any reference to `.modal` and found that a JS library I was using was moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```js
$(function () {
  //getting click event to show modal
    $('#submit-button').click(function () {
        $('#dialog_confirm_map').modal();
      //appending modal background inside the bigform-content
        $('.modal-backdrop').appendTo('.bigform-content');
      //removing body classes to able click events
        $('body').removeClass();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form>
<div class="bigform-content">    
    <div class="wpcol-one col-md-6">        
        <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit my form" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="dialog_confirm_map" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog_confirm_mapLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>-------MODAL BODY--------</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"> <span style="float:left"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button></span>
 <span style="float:right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" >Yes</button></span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
</form>
```